# Count the Number of Swaps in Selection Sort

Tags: java, sorting

I've read through all the discussions trying to find an answer but none of the answers have worked for me so I'm trying it this way.

```
public static int SelectionSort(long[] num)
{
    int i, j, first;
    long temp;
    int swap = 0;
    int pass = 0;
    int count = 0;
    boolean Mini = false;

    for (i = num.length - 1; i &gt; 0; i--)
    {
        for(int k = 0; k &lt; num.length; k++)
        {
            System.out.println(" k = " + k
            + "   \t X[i] = " + num[k] + " swap count: " + swap);
        }
        System.out.println("");
        first = 0;   //initialize to subscript of first element
        for(j = 1; j &lt;= i; j ++)   //locate smallest element between positions 1 and i.
        {
            if(num[j] &lt; num[first])
            {
                first = j;
                //Mini = true;
            }
        }

        //if(Mini){
            //  swap++;
        //}
        temp = num[first];   //swap smallest found with element in position i.
        num[first] = num[i];
        num[i] = temp;
    }
    return swap;
}
```

Using a simple array as my test case:

```
long[] X = {1, 4, 3, 2, 5};
```

The number of swaps should only equate to 1 because it's swapping the first and last elements only. However, it isn't working. While I know my if condition doesn't work, I can't think of what would. I can't seem to work the logic that it increments a swap when items are actually swapped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not increment the counter when you actually perform a swap?

```
//swap smallest found with element in position i.
swap++
temp = num[first];
num[first] = num[i];
num[i] = temp;
```

EDIT:
Good point in the comment. The current code still performs a superfluous swap if the array is sorted (i.e., `first` and `i` are the same):

```
if (first != i) { 
    swap++
    temp = num[first];
    num[first] = num[i];
    num[i] = temp;
}
```

Comment: the only issue with that is that the program will increment swap each time. I only want it to increment when it does swap. Right now if I increment swap there, it will give me a swap total of 4. It should only give me a swap of 1.

Answer (score 1):

With your implementation you will always have n swaps (where n is the number of elements in your array).

What I think you want is to only perform a swap when it actually makes a difference ... so when "first" and "i" have different values. Otherwise you switch the element with itself.

```
  if (first != i) {
    temp = num[first];
    num[first] = num[i];
    num[i] = temp; 
    swapp++;
  }
```